# XCode iOS .app missing - no such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

When trying to build my app, I get the following error:

```
CpResource /Users/chandlervdw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Inked-fnbfcyarvawgmdafoarjiaetlihv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Inked.app /Users/chandlervdw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Inked-fnbfcyarvawgmdafoarjiaetlihv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InkKit.framework/Inked.app
    cd /Users/chandlervdw/Repos/Inked
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/chandlervdw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Inked-fnbfcyarvawgmdafoarjiaetlihv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Inked.app /Users/chandlervdw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Inked-fnbfcyarvawgmdafoarjiaetlihv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InkKit.framework

error: /Users/chandlervdw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Inked-fnbfcyarvawgmdafoarjiaetlihv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Inked.app: No such file or directory
```

That file does not exist, but several linked resources have been copied there. I've cleaned my build and tried deleting all the files in `Derived Data` to no avail.

To note: This app was originally built in XCode-beta before iOS 9 was released.

Comment: I've also tried `sudo xcode-select --reset` and `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`...